"Warn me when I send a message that may be missing an attachment" Doesn't Work, New Outlook for Windows
I switched to the new version of Outlook for Windows (Windows 10), and while in general I am actually quite happy with the changes (contrary to popular opinion), there is one big issue that has been constantly annoying me.
Despite the fact that I have "Warn me when I send a message that may be missing an attachment" turned to the ON position in settings, Outlook never reminds me to send attachments! I have tried basic steps like toggling the setting on and off and restarting the application. No matter what, even in very "obvious" emails such as "The document you asked for is attached," Outlook never reminds me.
Does anyone have any experience fixing this or thoughts about how to approach the problem?

This feature is not supported in New Outlook at this time.
This is the feedback I found on the official feedback portal, and I will leave the feedback link for more people to see.
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/03a3d022-183d-ee11-a81c-6045bdbbbc93

It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. Have you had a chance to check the replies provided? Any update would be appreciated.

I don't think this response is accurate, as I can make the attachment reminder dialogue box appear intermittently. It appears, for example, that if I restart Outlook the attachment reminder works properly for the first email I send, but then it misses subsequent ones. Furthermore, it always works on my colleague's computer...
